# How to get specific properties from object based on property names selected at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class, let's say:

```
 public class Quote {

 public string City { get; set; }
 public string State { get; set; }
 string ZipCode { get; set; }
 public string HomeValue { get; set; }

}
```

Then I'm displaying every property name in a page with a checkbox next to them.
Let's say that `City` and `HomeValue` were selected.
Now when I query the database table 'Quote' I get all of the data on it, I need to filter that data and display on the results in the page only the selected properties with their related values...
How do I match the property names from the data I got from the database to the names that were selected...
Expected results for the example above would be:

```
City          HomeValue
Atlanta       234000
Orlando       435032

//All of the other values but just for `City` and `HomeValue` properties
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to retrieve the properties and it values. Check the following code snippets.

**Models:**

```
public class Quote
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string HomeValue { get; set; }
}

public class QuotesModel
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> Quotes { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedProps { get; set; } = AllProps;

    public static readonly string[] AllProps;
    static QuotesModel()
    {
        AllProps = typeof(Quote).GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.Name).ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Controller/Action**:

```
...
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Quotes([FromQuery] IList<string> props = null)
{
    if (props == null || !props.Any())
    {
        props = QuotesModel.AllProps;
    }

    var quotes = FetchQuotes();

    //--apply properties filter
    var selectedPropInfo = typeof(Quote).GetProperties().Where(p => props.Contains(p.Name)).ToList();

    var filteredQuotes = quotes
        .Select(quote => selectedPropInfo.ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name, pi => pi.GetValue(quote)))
        .ToList();

    var model = new QuotesModel
    {
        Quotes = filteredQuotes,
        SelectedProps = props.ToArray()
    };

    return View(model);
}
...
```

**To display the filtered objects:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var prop in Model.SelectedProps)
            {
                @:<td>@prop</td>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var q in Model.Quotes)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var prop in Model.SelectedProps)
                {
                    <td>@q[prop]</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs to be more clear. But if you are trying to load data from database and map them to properties of your `Quote` class, don't reinvent the wheel. Use Dapper:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Quote";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
   var quotes = connection.Query<Quote>(sql).ToList();
   // logic to process a List<Quote>
   ...
}
```

Link: https://stackexchange.github.io/Dapper/

Popular tutorials: https://dapper-tutorial.net/

If only certain columns are supposed to be loaded from database, then instead of "*" you need to put the column names together, perhaps using a `StringBuilder`. Depends on what you get after user checks those check boxes.

Comment: Do you have any question related to the post? I need to map selected property names to object property names in runtime, I don't have any issue retrieving the data from the database

Comment: Will take a look to Dapper and see if that helps, I'm using Entity Framework too though, I thought there would be a way to do this on the C# part...

Comment: @AlexGH, edited my answer. What data type/format is "selected property names"?